# What does this JavaScript expression in BIRT report mean?

Tags: javascript, report, expression, birt, semantics

I am working on a `BIRT` Report and one of the fields contains the following expression:

```
dataSetRow["user_id"] != dataSetRow["creatorId"] ? dataSetRow["orderCreator"] : ''
```

What is the logic of this statement?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator for reference on the ternary operator

Comment: the expression is called ternary operator..short form of if else where the expression evaluate based on true or false

Answer (score 2):

That statement is the equivalent of the code below, and is called the 'ternary' operator:

```
var value;

if(dataSetRow["creatorId"]){
    value = dataSetRow["orderCreator"];
}
else{
    value = '';
}

//To be clear, this isn't assigning to anything - this is the same expression you have in your question.
dataSetRow["user_id"] != value
```

You could use that expression, which returns a boolean, in an `if` block, for example:

```
if(dataSetRow["user_id"] != value){
    //Do something
}
```